# Calling a file with variable file name in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

Let's say that I have a source file named A with a lot of strings of 1 and 2, and whose content is being regurlarly and automatically changed (new strings of 1 and 2 are added), and that I perform a grep on this file to extract '1' strings into another file called B.

```
grep '1' A > B
```

Now the next grep operations must not only grep A content into B, but also compare B and A in order to extract new strings (and only new strings) into another file. This must be done repetitively. For that I create a new file C which contains the '1' strings of the updated content of A, compare it with B and extract the difference into a new file named D:

```
grep '1' A > B
sleep 60
while true; do
grep '1' A > C
grep -v -F -x -f B C > D
sleep 60
done &
```

The problem is that it won't work properly as B is an old grep of A, so the next time it runs C will only be compared to this old B that is not being updated. Furthermore, D is being overwritten each time.

I need to be able to instruct the script to each time keep a copy of last B, so A is always compared to its previous version, and C always shows the difference between current A and previous, last B. I don't need to keep previous versions of C as I copy them elsewhere.

I figured that I had to use variable file names and I tried to add a $(date) variable in B and C filenames, but obviously it doesn't work as grep doesn't recognize them (as the date changes between each run of the script).

PS: I found a workaround by wiping the content of A between each run, so that only new content is taken into consideration, which eliminates the necessity of using variable names and the second grep operation. I would still like to learn how to call variable file names in bash scripts.

PS2: I am writing on my phone, so don't know how to properly encode the bash script.

Comment: The question is a bit convoluted for me to follow.  However, there is a command called "comm" which will give you lines in A but not in B (comm -23 A B) and you can grep on that output.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply replace B ?

```
grep '1' A > B
sleep 60
while true; do
grep '1' A > C
grep -v -F -x -f B C > D
cat C >> B   ####
sleep 60
done &
```

this way `D` will only get last 60 sec of 1 in `A`.

Comment: @Paka - you should accept this answer